# JS use get in constructor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, getter

In a "basic" object, it's easy to define a 'get' property.

```js
var anObject = {
  get aProperty() {
    return "abc";
  }
}
document.write(anObject.aProperty); //abc
```

I find a solution to add a get property in a constructor function.

```js
var BasicConstructor = function ()
{
     Object.defineProperty(this, "aProperty", {get : function(){ return "abc"; }});
}
var anOtherObject = new BasicConstructor ();

document.write(anOtherObject.aProperty); //abc
```

Is their a more simple and readable solution ? I try some solution like the one below without success.

```js
var BasicConstructor = function ()
{
    this.aProperty = get ()
    {
        return "abc";
    }
}
var anOtherObject = new BasicConstructor ();

document.write(anOtherObject.aProperty); //abc
```

Comment: I just want to point out that `get aProperty()` is "new" notation. `Object.defineProperty` is the "old" one, meaning it's more widely supported by browsers.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: There is nothing new about this notation. FF supports it for 10 years now :-)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Its(`get aProperty()`) there from ES5

Comment: @Bergi Huh, my mistake. I was sure that `defineProperty` pre-dated `get/set`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question *is* tagged with [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6)

You can just use es6 class syntax and a getter:

```
class BasicConstructor {
    get aProperty() { return 'abc'; }
};
var anOtherObject = new BasicConstructor();

document.write(anOtherObject.aProperty); //abc
```

Comment: You could've gotten that in ES5 with `BasicConstructor.prototype = {get aProperty() { … }};` as well, but it's not in the constructor in either case.

Comment: Happy to help @JordaneCURE :-)

Comment: For sharing what i juste read - ecmascript-6 is't yet support by sevral browser (ie or android). So, the use of `class` will be a nice solution for tomorrow.

Comment: @JordaneCURE you can use a transpiler like BabelJs

Comment: @Neal Didn't know BabelJS, looks great.  If we compile your solution, the  `get` function is transform with the use of `Object.defineProperty ()`

Comment: @JordaneCURE yep. thats how babel does it to be able to work with older browsers.

Answer (score -1):

`this.aproperty = get () {}` is invalid syntax. you need the "function" keyword (and you don't really need the get at all, but you can keep it if you want)

```js
var BasicConstructor = function ()
{
    this.aProperty = function get ()
    {
        return "abc";
    }
}
var anOtherObject = new BasicConstructor ();
    
document.write(anOtherObject.aProperty()); //abc
```

Comment: But now you'd have to do `anOtherObject.aProperty()` to get `"abc"`

Comment: I just copied his code, I thought writing out the property was onpurpose.   You "call" anotherObject.aproperty with parentheses...I'll edit the snippit..

Comment: @RayWadkins: But that's not what the OP wants

Comment: With this solution we have to call the function aProperty () not acces to it with the `get`